# Apache Nutch hangs indefinitely on updatedb when dealing with 1 million+ fetched pages

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, nutch

I've been using Apache Nutch for awhile and it works well so long as my fetches stay below 1 million or so pages. But once I get into the millions, updatedb takes forever and never finishes - I've waited days and days, almost a week one time for it to finish.

Is there an obvious reason for this? And if so, is there any alleviation?

I've seen talk of using Hadoop instead of HBase and I've tried to use Hadoop but came across many issues. But, could that fix it?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you share some details, the Nutch version, how it's called including all command-line and Java options, the on which platform it runs, etc. Just to confirm: Nutch is able to work with a CrawlDb of 10 billion URLs and more.

Comment: I'm using Nutch 2.3. I am calling each command manually, over and over again: inject, generate, fetch, parse and updatedb.   I use -all wherever applicable, like on fetch and parse and updatedb. And for generate I use -topN 10000000. And I'm running this on Debian 9. Does it matter than I'm using HBase instead of Hadoop?

Comment: HBase and Hadoop are not mutually exclusive. However, I strongly recommend to use Nutch 1.15 - it's easier to setup, requires less experience with big data stores such as HBase, it provides more features and it's actively maintained.

Comment: All right - I will give it a shot. But just to clarify, my original issue has nothing to do with HBase or Nutch inherently? 1 million pages in the crawldb should process in a timely manner?

Comment: No, if configured right 1 million pages should work. It could be a trivial configuration issue, e.g., to less Java heap space for HBase or Nutch cause the JVM spend a lot of time for garbage collection.

Comment: How would I increase the Java heap space for HBase?

Comment: into bin/nutch you can increase Xmx. by default is 1000

Comment: I have increased to 16g, should that be enough? I'm still getting hanging.